# How to know which model of YOLO is the best for detection with the outputs during training?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I'm using YOLO for object detection. The results that is shown at the end of the training are precision, recall and mAP50. I want to find the better hyper parameters for better detection. I'm looking for the highest IoUs. That means lowest box-loss. But based on the above matrices how should I know which model is better?